# Best Way To Find Live Data From A Web Service

Tags: database, web-services

When you guys need live data for example sports stats, or music lyrics where would you go to get the data? Do you have to pay for this? Are there web services available to consume this live data? Whats broadly the process of getting constant access to live data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A good one for music related data is [musicbrainz.org](http://musicbrainz.org)

Answer (score 0):

If you Google "[random data](http://www.google.com/search?q=random+data)", you will find a number of websites out there making available realtime random data for anyone's use. The [Random.org](http://www.random.org/) website is one such example.

Any random input may be translated into another random construct, depending on the requirements of the project. (for example, a random number between 0 and 1 may be translated into a 'heads' if number is <0.5 and 'tails', when otherwise - of course, other examples abound, and the 'random.org' website lists a number of examples of how people have used their data.

One of the benefits of culling data from 'atmospheric' noise, or some similar natural phenomenon, is that you are not at the mercy of it ever stopping to produce data! That being said, I realize you may have meant data of an entirely different form, and I'd also be curious of other sources of live data, beyond the usual feeds from different aggregator websites.